# "The filename or extension is too long error" using gradle

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, gradle, cmd

I have recently updated my code and when I tried to run our application using **g bootRun** in the command line, I encountered this error.

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61) Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:327)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40) Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
        ... 2 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\Work\FBXX"): CreateProcess  error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 5 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        ... 6 more
```

Here's the task in gradle:

```
  bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        args project.args.split('\\s+')
    }
  }
```

We have tried reducing the directory path of our project but we're looking for another solution.

This is the current directory path of our project:

> D:\Work\FBXX

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/10598074/1997376 ?

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434482/how-can-i-create-a-pathing-jar-in-gradle

Comment: You should provide `build.gradle` file! without it, we can only guess! Did you use something like `classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main"`? If so, replace it with `sourceSets.main.compileClasspath`. In my experience, the former concatenates all `.class` paths and forms a  very long string to be used as an argument to `java -classpath` command and therefore causes `The filename or extension is too long` error.

Answer (score 20):

Just add this plugin **ManifestClasspath** in your build.gradle file and specify the manifest classpath.
ManifestClasspath plugin creates a manifest jar for jar files in the classpath of JavaExec task and sets the classpath with the manifest jar.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"       
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.example.demo.Application'
dependencies {

 }
```

Comment: Just adding below to my build.gradle file worked for me:

plugins {
    id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"       
}

Answer (score 16):

I had similar problem, in my situation this works fine:

```
 task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
      dependsOn configurations.runtime
      appendix = 'pathing'

      doFirst {
         manifest {
             attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.files.collect {it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst("file:/", '/')}.join(" ")
         }
     }
 }
 bootRun {
     dependsOn pathingJar
     doFirst {
         classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
     }
 }
```

Comment: This worked once I corrected the classpath to `classpath = files(sourceSets.main.output.files, pathingJar.archivePath)`

Comment: This was broken for me. I am using gradle 4.10.3. In gradle 4.x, the runtime configuration is deprecated. I replaced "runtime" with "runtimeClasspath" and it worked.

Answer (score 16):

If you use JetBrains Intellij Idea, you could solve it with one simple setting. Go to Run/Debug configuration and set Shorten command line to "JAR manifest". You should set it for each configuration you run, though.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is for a Spring Boot application. This question is about running something via gradle. Your answer does not seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thank you so much for posting this answer, saved the day.

Answer (score 13):

Recently I have the same problem and this plugin solved it!
https://github.com/viswaramamoorthy/gradle-util-plugins

Answer (score 1):

boot module do this:

```
if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
    task classpathJar(type: Jar) {
        dependsOn configurations.runtime
        appendix = 'classpath'

        doFirst {
            manifest {
                attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                    it.toURI().toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/').replaceAll(' ', '%20')
                }.join(' ')
            }
        }
    }

    bootRun {
        dependsOn classpathJar
        doFirst {
            classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/java/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", classpathJar.archivePath)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Grails 3 project working on Windows 8.1 but not in Windows 10. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51637527/2835520) helped me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.viswaramamoorthy:gradle-util-plugins:0.1.0-RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.ManifestClasspath"
```

[Link to gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath)

Answer (score 1):

Even though this post is late, may be it helps someone.
In Run --> Edit Configurations -->   select the application you want to run --> Build and run --> More options --> Select manifast jar.

It worked under this intellij version ::: 2021.1.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I found the command line was becoming too long was because of some kind of unique id used by gradle in file path.

for example gradle uses jar file **el-impl-2.1.2-b03.jar** from

`C:\Users\bob\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.web\el-impl\2.1.2-b03\6bab1211b6e6b191fdbf06067bd05d2f75a62ac0\el-impl-2.1.2-b03.jar`

while the same file in maven is at

```
C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\web\el-impl\2.1.2-b03\el-impl-2.1.2-b03.jar
```

That is 90 chars vs 150 chars. So if we put the same artifacts in maven, overall size of command line becomes small.

Use these steps to install the jars that can be found in central maven repo to your local maven repo. Then use mavenLocal() as repo in you gradle build file.

Step 1) Create a dependency report

```
gradlew dependencies > tmp.txt
```

Step 2) Create a batch file to downloads the dependencies (I use cygwin, if you don't have then use another Linux machine to exeute this command and create install.To.Maven.bat file (note: *dos2unix* may need to be replaced by *fromdos*)

```
cat tmp.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep ':' | grep -e org -e com | sort -u  | xargs -n 1 -I fullname echo call mvn  dependency:get -Dartifact=fullname | dos2unix > install.To.Maven.bat
```

Step 3)
Run the bat file to download and install artifacts into local maven repo.

```
install.To.Maven.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

I too face this problem often. Sometimes just shortening the command line using IntelliJ Edit configurations would solve the issue like mentioned in above comments.

If the above approach didn't work, then simply delete the jar files in the build directory of the project and then it will work.