# Execution failed for task ':bootRun'

Tags: gradle, grails, bootrun

i got this app from company's repo, and when i try to bootRun my app in Grails 3.1.3, i got this issue. The full stacktrace is below.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe''

- What I tried:

> Run with --stacktrace to get more log output.

The exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe''
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:327)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)

Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'
  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
  ... 2 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\My Documents\HadI\Fairtech\michelin_sg"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
  ... 5 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
  ... 6 more
```

I have tried googling the solution but i cant find it. Maybe in this forum someone can help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: google for `The filename or extension is too long`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say what Grails version but for Grails 3, adding the following to build.gradle worked for me.

```
grails {
    pathingJar = true
}
```

**Update September 2020**
Upgrade to gradle 6+ where the issue has been [addressed](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/release-notes.html?_ga=2.223878815.521226841.1600452858-1620606703.1600452858#usability-improvements)

Comment: This make assets fail, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63943690/2835520) instead.

Comment: Thanks :) @Mike W

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the previous answer (not enough reputation) but I felt it interesting to explain the reason behind the fix.

This is a Windows specific issue I encountered when changing a Grails 3.3 project from OSX to Windows.

Windows sets a fixed number of characters that can be passed in the command line. Supposedly this error can occur even when unzipping a file if the path is too long.

Moving your project to the root of your OS (near C:) can sometimes solve this issue if your path gets under the character threshold.

**pathingJar** fixes your paths to not exceed this limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Intellij IDEA try to check 'Shorten command line' in Run\Debug

Configuration,switch it to classpath file, in my case is helped.

[image]