# Can't able to include spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to include Cassandra dependency in my spring-boot project
But it fails to compile.

It works fine when I include single dependency of

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'

in another demo project, but with another dependencies it doesn't able to work

Here is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') 
    testCompile ('org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25')
    implementation ('org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:1.10.1')
    implementation ('org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro:1.10.1')
    implementation ('org.json:json:20171018')
    implementation ('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0')
    runtimeOnly    ('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    implementation ('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1')
    implementation ('log4j:log4j:1.2.17')
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I would be grateful if you tell me which dependency abstains the Cassandra to run

Comment: Could you please add the error?

Comment: I resolved that issue it was the Gradle plugin issue in Windows[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037487/the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-error-using-gradle/55589825#55589825)