# Jhipster gradle build 6.0.0 jdk-11 How to fix a failing build?

Tags: build.gradle, jhipster

I created a project with JHipster 6.0.0-beta.0 and java version openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64

I get the following error.

> Task :bootRun FAILED
>   Error: Could not find or load main class com.jhipster.demo.desc.DescApp
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\OpenJDK11\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my build.gradle file

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE"
        //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "maven"
    id "war"
    id "idea"
    id "jacoco"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "0.9.11"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.0.0"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.21"
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "2.0.1"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}

sourceCompatibility=1.8
targetCompatibility=1.8
assert System.properties["java.specification.version"] == "1.8" || "11" || "12"

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "propdeps"

apply from: "gradle/docker.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/sonar.gradle"
//jhipster-needle-gradle-apply-from - JHipster will add additional gradle scripts to be applied here

if (project.hasProperty("prod")) {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_prod.gradle"
} else {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_dev.gradle"
}

if (project.hasProperty("zipkin")) {
    apply from: "gradle/zipkin.gradle"
}

idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += files("node_modules")
    }
}

eclipse {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += ["build/generated/source/apt/main"]
            }
        }
    }
}

defaultTasks "bootRun"

group = "com.jhipster.demo.desc"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

description = ""

bootWar {
    mainClassName = "com.jhipster.demo.desc.DescApp"
    includes = ["WEB-INF/**", "META-INF/**"]
}

war {
    enabled = true
    extension = "war.original"
    includes = ["WEB-INF/**", "META-INF/**"]
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.jhipster.demo.desc.DescApp"
}

if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037487/the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-error-using-gradle
    task classpathJar(type: Jar) {
        dependsOn configurations.runtime
        appendix = "classpath"

        doFirst {
            manifest {
                attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                    it.toURI().toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20")
                }.join(" ")
            }
        }
    }

    bootRun {
        dependsOn classpathJar
        doFirst {
            classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/java/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", classpathJar.archivePath)
        }
    }
}

test {
    exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*", "**/*CucumberIT*"

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Execute integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    include "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"
    exclude "**/*CucumberIT*"

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task cucumberTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Execute cucumber BDD tests."
    group = "verification"
    include "**/*CucumberIT*"

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

check.dependsOn cucumberTest

check.dependsOn integrationTest
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn test
}

task integrationTestReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn integrationTest
}

task cucumberTestReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn cucumberTest
}

if (!project.hasProperty("runList")) {
    project.ext.runList = "main"
}

project.ext.diffChangelogFile = "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/" + new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_changelog.xml"

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/desc"
            username "root"
            password ""
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml"
            defaultSchemaName "desc"
            logLevel "debug"
            classpath "src/main/resources/"
        }
        diffLog {
            driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/desc"
            username "root"
            password ""
            changeLogFile project.ext.diffChangelogFile
            referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:com.jhipster.demo.desc.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
            defaultSchemaName "desc"
            logLevel "debug"
            classpath "$buildDir/classes/java/main"
        }
    }

    runList = project.ext.runList
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    implementation.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-repositories - JHipster will add additional repositories
}

dependencies {
    // import JHipster dependencies BOM
    implementation platform("io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}" )

    // Use ", version: jhipster_dependencies_version, changing: true" if you want
    // to use a SNAPSHOT release instead of a stable release
    implementation group: "io.github.jhipster", name: "jhipster-framework"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
    implementation "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core"
    implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner"
    implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast"
    implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-hibernate53"
    implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring"
    implementation "javax.cache:cache-api"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io"
    implementation "javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers"
    implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator"
    implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:${liquibase_hibernate5_version}"
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch"
    // Spring Data Jest dependencies for Elasticsearch
    implementation ("com.github.vanroy:spring-boot-starter-data-jest") {
        exclude module: "commons-logging"
    }
    // log4j2-mock needed to create embedded elasticsearch instance with SLF4J
    runtimeOnly "de.dentrassi.elasticsearch:log4j2-mock:0.0.1"
    // end of Spring Data Jest dependencies
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka"
    implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix"
    implementation "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
    implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson"
    implementation ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2") {
        exclude module: "mapstruct"
    }
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    liquibaseRuntime "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstruct_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstruct_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernate_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"
    annotationProcessor ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${spring_boot_version}") {
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module: "android-json"
    }
    testImplementation "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-spring"
    testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module: "android-json"
    }
    testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core"
    testImplementation "junit:junit"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library"
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency - JHipster will add additional dependencies here
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
    delete "build/resources"
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "5.3.1"
}
compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn bootBuildInfo
```

I would expect this to compile successfully.

Updated Gradle File (4/12/19)

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE"
    **classpath "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"
    classpath "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:${jaxb_api_version}"**
        //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "maven"
    id "war"
    id "idea"
    id "jacoco"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "0.9.11"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.0.0"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.21"
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "2.0.1"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}

    **sourceCompatibility=1.11
    targetCompatibility=1.11**

assert System.properties["java.specification.version"] == "1.8" || "11" || "12"

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "propdeps"

apply from: "gradle/docker.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/sonar.gradle"
//jhipster-needle-gradle-apply-from - JHipster will add additional gradle scripts to be applied here

if (project.hasProperty("prod")) {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_prod.gradle"
} else {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_dev.gradle"
}

if (project.hasProperty("zipkin")) {
    apply from: "gradle/zipkin.gradle"
}

idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += files("node_modules")
    }
}

eclipse {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += ["build/generated/source/apt/main"]
            }
        }
    }
}

defaultTasks "bootRun"

group = "com.jhipster.demo.descriptions"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

description = ""

bootWar {
    mainClassName = "com.jhipster.demo.descriptions.DescriptionsApp"
    includes = ["WEB-INF/**", "META-INF/**"]
}

war {
    enabled = true
    extension = "war.original"
    includes = ["WEB-INF/**", "META-INF/**"]
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.jhipster.demo.descriptions.DescriptionsApp"
}

if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037487/the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-error-using-gradle
    task classpathJar(type: Jar) {
        dependsOn configurations.runtime
        appendix = "classpath"

        doFirst {
            manifest {
                attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                    it.toURI().toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20")
                }.join(" ")
            }
        }
    }

    bootRun {
        dependsOn classpathJar
        doFirst {
            classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/java/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", classpathJar.archivePath)
        }
    }
}

test {
    exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*", "**/*CucumberIT*"

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Execute integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    include "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"
    exclude "**/*CucumberIT*"

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task cucumberTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Execute cucumber BDD tests."
    group = "verification"
    include "**/*CucumberIT*"

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

check.dependsOn cucumberTest

check.dependsOn integrationTest
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn test
}

task integrationTestReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn integrationTest
}

task cucumberTestReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn cucumberTest
}

if (!project.hasProperty("runList")) {
    project.ext.runList = "main"
}

project.ext.diffChangelogFile = "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/" + new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_changelog.xml"

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/descriptions"
            username "root"
            password ""
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml"
            defaultSchemaName "descriptions"
            logLevel "debug"
            classpath "src/main/resources/"
        }
        diffLog {
            driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/descriptions"
            username "root"
            password ""
            changeLogFile project.ext.diffChangelogFile
            referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:com.jhipster.demo.descriptions.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
            defaultSchemaName "descriptions"
            logLevel "debug"
            classpath "$buildDir/classes/java/main"
        }
    }

    runList = project.ext.runList
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    implementation.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-repositories - JHipster will add additional repositories
}

dependencies {
    // import JHipster dependencies BOM
    implementation platform("io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}" )

    // Use ", version: jhipster_dependencies_version, changing: true" if you want
    // to use a SNAPSHOT release instead of a stable release
    implementation group: "io.github.jhipster", name: "jhipster-framework"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
    implementation "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core"
    implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner"
    implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast"
    implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-hibernate53"
    implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring"
    implementation "javax.cache:cache-api"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io"
    implementation "javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers"
    implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator"
    implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:${liquibase_hibernate5_version}"
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch"
    // Spring Data Jest dependencies for Elasticsearch
    implementation ("com.github.vanroy:spring-boot-starter-data-jest") {
        exclude module: "commons-logging"
    }
    // log4j2-mock needed to create embedded elasticsearch instance with SLF4J
    runtimeOnly "de.dentrassi.elasticsearch:log4j2-mock:0.0.1"
    // end of Spring Data Jest dependencies
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka"
    implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix"
    implementation "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
    implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson"
    implementation ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2") {
        exclude module: "mapstruct"
    }
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    liquibaseRuntime "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstruct_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstruct_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernate_version}"
**implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:${jaxb_api_version}"
annotationProcessor "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:${jaxb_api_version}"
implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"
annotationProcessor "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"**
    annotationProcessor ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${spring_boot_version}") {
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module: "android-json"
    }
    testImplementation "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-spring"
    testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module: "android-json"
    }
    testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core"
    testImplementation "junit:junit"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library"
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency - JHipster will add additional dependencies here
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
    delete "build/resources"
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "5.3.1"
}
compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn bootBuildInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can fix this by adding JAXB to your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime'
```

If this works, please open an issue (or create a PR) in the [JHipster project on GitHub](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster).

Comment: Thank you for the response Matt. I think i correctly added the JAXB to my gradle file (though i am very new to coding and could have some thing wrong still), and i am still not able to build successfully. I added my new gradle.build file above with the changes i made for jaxb. (jaxb_runtime_version(2.3.2) & jaxb_api_version(2.3.1) versions are defined in my gradle.properties file). If you notice something that is not correct, please let me know.