# Gradle task `bootrun` setup in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am running `gradle bootRun`

```
gradle bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=local' --stacktrace
```

I am getting a `CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long exception`

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :bootRun FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\JDK8\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe''
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        ...
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\JDK8\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:231)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:209)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:355)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\JDK8\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:67)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\JDK8\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\E080978\git\order-management-api"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
        ... 8 more
```

My configurations:
- Gradle Version: 4.9
- JDK Version: jdk1.8.0_111
- Windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main)

Comment: Can someone remove duplicate. My question is regarding the exception for IntelliJ and the answer is given for Eclipse bug

Comment: @MebinJoe Changed question

Comment: @AymanArif Voting to reopen. The linked duplicate is clearly not remotely relevant for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Gradle on windows, you may encounter this error if you have a large number of dependencies in your classpath. This is due to the limitation on number of characters in executing command.

Try this solution from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037487/the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-error-using-gradle):

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"       
}

apply plugin: "com.github.ManifestClasspath"

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.pb.ngp.identity.manager.KeyManagerApplication'
}
```

You may encounter following error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

Then simply specify the main class. e.g.

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.SpringBootApplication'
}
```