# Execution failed for task ':bootRun'. CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, intellij-idea

I have SpringBoot app build using gradle. When I introduced @Async Executor service, the app does not start using bootRun in intellij nor it runs over command line. Any pointers to what could be going wrong ?

Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe''

CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Comment: Let me guess, you are on windows?

Comment: yes.. I am on Windows..

Comment: This one helped me fix this ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756002/4564749